Coefficient functions of local orthonormal frame with unit speed
This is part of the proof of Proposition 13.19 Flatness Criterion for Surfaces of Revolution from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. Here, we set $C$ to be a connected embedded $1$-dimensional submanifold of the half plane $H=\{(r,z):r>0\}$ and let $S_C$ be the surface of revolution generated by $C$. We assume that $S_C$ is flat, and show that $C$ will be part of a straight line. Let $\gamma(t)=(a(t),b(t))$ be a local parametrization of $C$ with unit speed. Then the induced metric is $dt^2 + a^2 d\theta^2$ and the local frame $(E_1,E_2)$ given by
$$E_1= \partial /\partial t, E_2 = \frac{1}{a} \partial / \partial d\theta$$ is orthonormal. Any other orthonormal frame $(\tilde{E}_1,\tilde{E}_2)$ can be written in the form $$\tilde{E}_1 = uE_1 + vE_2, \pm \tilde{E}_2 = vE_1 - uE_2,$$ for some functions $u$ and $v$ depending smoothly on $(t,\theta)$ and $u^2+v^2=1$.
Why must the coefficient functions for $\tilde{E}_1$ and $\tilde{E}_2$ in terms of $E_1,E_2$ given by this relation? I can't figure out why we must have $(v,-u)$ as the components for $\tilde{E}_2$.

Any real relation $u^2+v^2=1$ can be reparametized by a 2d rotation $$(u,v) =(\cos \phi \  u' -\sin \phi \ v',\quad  \cos phi  \ v' + \sin \phi \ u' )$$ preserving lenghts and angles.
